# Git-lab push that assigned to a issue and make issue done

Tags: android, android-studio, gitlab, issue-tracking

is there any way to push a commit from android Studio that assigned to a issue that make issue **done** ?
my Git-lab is on our corporation Local serverand it's version is **GitLab Community Edition 8.5.0**  I tried:

```
Closes #issuenumber
Fixes #issuenumber
```

but these not works and just Gitlab findouts that my issue mentioned in commit.
I found this [link](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/issues/394) with same problem. I also do:

- Edit `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` and add the line `gitlab_rails['gitlab_issue_closing_pattern'] = '((?:[Cc]los(?:e[sd]|ing)|[Ff]ix(?:e[sd]|ing)?) +(?:(?:issues? +)?#\d+(?:(?:, *| +and +)?))+)'`
- Run `gitlab-ctl reconfigure`

but it does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

According to this page on [GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/2013/09/22/gitlab-community-edition-6-dot-1-released/)

> When you create a commit with a message starting with ‘Fixes #1’ or 'Closes #1’ and push it to master GitLab will close the issue you referred to. If you create a Merge Request targeting master with commits in it that will close Issues, GitLab will tell you which Issues will be closed.

That should solve your problem

Comment: is it automatically close the issue?

Comment: Yes, if your commit message starts with "Closes #1" it will close the issue

Comment: I use this code but in server side it says that mentioned in commit 14d1c055. but issue still open :(

Comment: Are you sure that the #1 is replaced by the issue number of gitlab and has been pushed to remote?

Comment: yes. it pushed and updated by comment that i said to you. mentioned in commit 14d1c055(my commit number)

Comment: Which version of gitlab are you using? However 14d1c055 is not the issue number of gitlab, can you show me a screenshot of the gitlab issue where the issue number is shown?

Comment: If you put in your commit message, exactly this: "Closes #2 This commit will close this issue" and do a git push to the gitlab server, it should close this. If this isn't the case, can you show the git log within GitLab?

Comment: my gitlab is on local server in corporation. is it needs some settings in project with root user?

Comment: @SlashmanX No, I'm on non master branch. but it's origin.  origin/myBranch

Comment: @Kenji that's your problem, it only works on the master branch